# Evaluate CSS calc function in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to figure out a way to execute the CSS calc function directly in my js file in order to compare two elements height.

So let's say i have two elements that I get using jQuery, and all I want to do is something around those simple lines :

```
if (element1.height > element2.height) then ...
```

Element2 is nested within Element1, who has an `overflow:scroll.`

Problem is, my element1 has **all attributes** clientHeight, scrollHeight,etc **equals to 0** and when i go in the element1.style.height the result is : "calc(100% - 64px)". *Please do note that the result of this is never equal to 0px since my element1 height when i inspect it is around 500px (of course depends of the screen size)*. And my element2 height is obtained in px using element2.scrollHeight (more reliable in my case).

So in the end I'm trying to compare two expressions that would like this : calc(100% - 64px) > 452 .. And of course this doesn't work.

Is there any way I could execute the calc() function within my js file to get the equivalent height in px in order to compare my two elements ? Or can I have access to the data anywhere else ?

My end goal is to know whether the element2's height is bigger than element1's. So any other implementation that height calculation is welcome as well.

Comment: Although a description can be useful, it would be so much clearer if you provided actual code (but not more than necessary) with which the problem can be reproduced.

Comment: @GuillaumeRoche-Bayard Not trying to be rude but to improve readability for others, if you could format your question better, we can help you. This is from "why this is worth a downvote" section: 

Without the code, the question is not answerable. Any solution would be based on guesses. Even if someone guessed right, not having any code means it’s harder to relate for future readers. Questions that aren’t useful for people other than the asker are discouraged on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the computed style using [Window.getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle). Check out the [compatibility table](https://caniuse.com/#search=getComputedStyle).

Then, grab the `width` and remove the "px" from the result, and parse it to an integer:

```js
let myElement = document.getElementById('child');
let width = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(myElement).width.slice(0, -2), 10);
console.log(width);
```

```css
#parent {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 80%;
}

#child {
  background: green;
  height: 60px;
  width: calc(100% - 64px);
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is that getComputedStyle actually returns the data with 'calc(100% - 64px)' and not the actual value.

Comment: Ok it seems to work on your case i'll try to figure out what is not working on mine, thanks for the info I didn't know that method :).

Comment: @GuillaumeRoche-Bayard Check out the new sample, and make sure you are reading the `height`/`width` property from the result of getComputedStyle(). Make sure you place your JS code before the closing `</body>` tag to make sure the page is completely rendered, unless you are doing it in an event based way.